# vueでassetsのpdfを取得する方法

Tags: javascript, vue.js

私は今、vue.jsでウェブアプリの開発をしています。
下記のように、assetsに配置しているpdfファイルをダウンロードできる画面作成したいのですがエラーとなってしまいます。
方法を教えてください。

```
<template>
  <a href="./../assets/sample.pdf" download>sample.pdf download</a>
</template>
```

エラーメッセージは以下の通りです。宜しくお願い致します。

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no lo     ders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concept     #loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

Comment: 解決しました。PDFファイルをpublicに配置し、
<template>
  <a href="sample.pdf" download>sample.pdf download</a>
</template>
とするだけでした。

Comment: 解決した場合にはコメント欄ではなく、ぜひ「個別の回答」として投稿してみてください。参考ヘルプ: [自分の質問に回答できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)